# Showing an unknown loose edge in object mode

Tags: edges

There is a loose edge that I never or I don't remember how I created shown in the object mode.
The loose edge disappears in edit mode so I can't remove it.
Can somebody help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDAAp.png)

[image]

Comment: maybe hidden? try alt+h in edit mode.

Comment: Nothing hidden.